# retrieving specific fileds using JestClient in elastic Serach

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have the following document stored in elastic search

```
{"Book_Id" : "102" ,"Book_Name" : "Alice in wonderLand", "Review_Text" :"DescentRead","Rating_Percentage" :"100" }'
{"Book_Id" : "102" ,"Book_Name" : "Alice in wonderLand", "Review_Text" :"For Kids","Rating_Percentage" :"50" }'
{"Book_Id" : "103" ,"Book_Name" : "Blah Blah", "Review_Text" :"Great","Rating_Percentage" :"100" }'
```

I want to do a search and retrieve only one field(Review Text in this example) as an out put.I am using the following code

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();  
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Book_Id", "102"))
        .fields("_source.Review_Text");
Search search = new Search.Builder(searchSourceBuilder.toString())
                .addIndex("reviews")
                .addType("bookreview")
                .build();
```

SearchResult result = client.execute(search);

But I keep getting the error -

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Deprecated field [fields] used, expected [stored_fields] instead","line":10,"col":14}],
```

what is missing here ? How else do we retrieve only specific fileds instead of all the fields as Json

Thanks
Shabna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `fields` directly is deprecated as described in the error message. Use [`source` filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) instead:

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();  
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Book_Id", "102"))
        .fetchSource("Review_Text", null);                    <-- change this line
Search search = new Search.Builder(searchSourceBuilder.toString())
                .addIndex("reviews")
                .addType("bookreview")
                .build();
```

Comment: fetchSource is undefined for SearchSourceBuilder .

Comment: Which version of the elasticsearch library are you using?

Comment: Got it working !Thanks a lot after changing the version of elastic serach

Comment: When I access two filed the resulting json is of the following format as expected.             
             
                {"Book_Id":"102","Review_Text":"DescentRead"},{"Book_Id":"102","Review_Text":"For Kids."},{"Book_Id":"103","Review_Text":"Great"}
                
                Is it possible to aggregate the multiple values of a particular field into an array  based on  id 
                
                for example:
                
             [ { Book_Id: 102, Review_Text: [ "DescentRead", "For Kids", ....], { Book_Id: 103, reviews: [ "Great"] } ]

Comment: Not in the source directly but you can get a semantically equivalent response by using aggregations.

Comment: In the Jest repo, they have some test class that shows how to go around terms aggregations: https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/af2e137311b1ce56ebe233b243b74fa2eed6ace3/jest/src/test/java/io/searchbox/core/search/aggregation/TermsAggregationIntegrationTest.java

Comment: No you can construct it using Java/Jest classes, but please create another question so we don't mix topics together

Comment: moving to a diff query